# Issue with SelectSingleNode

Tags: c#, xml

My plan is to use the XML below to randomly select one of the `event` nodes and then assign some of the nodes for each `choice` node to strings (there will, ultimately, be more `choice` nodes in each event). However, before I even get to going through all the choices, I hit a snag.

I use this piece of code:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
XmlNode mainNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("events");

XmlNodeList nodeList = mainNode.ChildNodes;
int random = Program.rand.Next(0, nodeList.Count);

XmlNode optionNode = mainNode.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("event[@id='{0}']", random));
Console.WriteLine(mainNode.InnerText);
Console.WriteLine(optionNode.InnerText);
```

Which results in a `NullReferenceException` on the last line.

Here is the XML:

```
<events>
    <event id="333">
        <name>Test event 1</name>
        <text>Something something</text>
    <choices>
        <choice id="1">
            <choicebutton>Button 1 from choice 1</choicebutton>
            <choiseresulttext>Something happened</choiseresulttext>
        </choice>
        <choice id="2">
            <choicebutton>Button 2 from choice 1</choicebutton>
            <choiseresulttext>Something else happened</choiseresulttext>
        </choice>
    </choices>
</event>
<event id="2">
    <name>Test event 2</name>
    <text>Something something more</text>
    <choices>
        <choice id="1">
            <choicebutton>Button 1 from choice 2</choicebutton>
            <choiseresulttext>Something happened</choiseresulttext>
        </choice>
        <choice id="2">
            <choicebutton>Button 2 from choice 2</choicebutton>
            <choiseresulttext>Something else happened</choiseresulttext>
        </choice>
    </choices>
</event>
```

The `Console.WriteLine(mainNode.InnerText);` line executes properly, so I assume the problem is with the way I assign the node to `optionNode`. Did I make any mistake in this statement, or is this some larger misunderstandment on my part?

Comment: `nodeList.Count - 1`

Comment: first event has id 333. It should start from id = "0" if you are using random ids from 0 to count of events

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my stupidity, @SergeyBerezovskiy. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
XmlNode mainNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("events");

XmlNodeList nodeList = mainNode.ChildNodes;
int random = Program.rand.Next(0, nodeList.Count - 1);

XmlNode optionNode = nodeList[random];
Console.WriteLine(mainNode.InnerText);
Console.WriteLine(optionNode.InnerText);
```